# flash messages are not showing on live server but showing locally

Tags: php, yii2, plesk

I am debugging a yii2 application, I simply copied project to debug, the problem is that locally flash messages are showing but on live plesk linux server, the flash messages are not showing for the same yii2 app.

I noticed in backend/config/main.php session component is not defined, could it be the issue? and where do I locate session file in linux server to make sure if session is being generated.

```
'components' => [
    'errorHandler' => [
        'errorAction' => 'site/error',
    ],
    'assetManager' => $assets,
    'authManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
        // uncomment if you want to cache RBAC items hierarchy
        // 'cache' => 'cache',
    ],
    'urlManager' => [
        'rules' => [
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:[a-zA-ZöäüßÖÄÜ\-]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:[a-zA-ZöäüßÖÄÜ\-]+>'          => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'                             => '<controller>/view',
        ],
    ],
],
```

In Xamp, I can see sessions are being created in `Xamp/Temp` folder, and on linux server `var/lib/php5/sessions` i can see session being created as in temp. But on live server session is not showing.

btw I just started learning yii2, incase my question sounds basic.

Comment: Yes, you need working session in order to work with _flash messages_.

Comment: but it works locally, shouldn't session be an issue then also? @Justinas

Comment: It would not be an issue if you had identical setup